# I have a base class. How do I call the right method for the right derived class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Obviously trying to simplify the problem here. I have a base class and a number of derived classes:

```
public class Mammal { }

public class Cat : Mammal { } 

public class Dog : Mammal { }
```

And a utility class:

```
public static class AnotherClass
{
    public static void GiveFood(Cat cat) {}
    public static void GiveFood(Dog dog) {}
}
```

Somewhere else is a method, Feed, which takes a Mammal, and from within there i want to call the right overload on AnotherClass:

```
public void Feed(Mammal mammal) {
    // if mammal is a cat, call the AnotherClass.GiveFood overload for cat,
    // if it's a dog, call the AnotherClass.GiveFood for dog, etc.
}
```

One way to do that would be to do something like:

```
public void Feed(Mammal mammal) {
    if (mammal is dog) 
        AnotherClass.GiveFood((Dog)mammal);
    if (mammal is Cat) 
        AnotherClass.GiveFood((Cat)mammal);
}
```

...but I actually have a huge number of animals derived from Mammal. Is there a nicer way to do what I want to do in Feed()? Is there any way I can avoid having Feed() end up being a huge ugly method filled with these "if x is y then call z"-statements?

Comment: Look up "visitor pattern"

Comment: Ideally you'd have a `TakeFood` method in `Mammal` and then `AnotherClass` can just accept a `Mammal` object in `GiveFood` and you allow the virtual dispatch to take care of everything.

Comment: @Servy That approach is good if it works, but if there's state involved that `Mammal` is ignorant of (say, something that tracks how much and what kind of food is given to each animal every day), there can be merit in a visitor approach too.

Comment: I'd wager the idea could be that GiveFood is giving specific food and/or quantities to specific animals. You don't want to feed your cat purina puppy chow. In which case, you do need some tailored behavior independent of the animal.

Comment: Just wonder... why `GiveFood` is not virtual method of `Mammal`?

Comment: @user414076 That depends on whether or not your cat implements `IGarfield`.

Comment: @tia It would probably make sense for `Mammal` to have a `Feed()` method of some kind, but maybe `GiveFood()` has to do other stuff on top of that, such as keeping track of nutritional information for each animal, notifying the zoo(?) that it's running low on Monkey Chow, etc. -- stuff that the `Mammal` class doesn't need to be concerned with.

Comment: @Jeremy while that certainly is not the responsibility of the animal, neither is it of the feeder. The Feeder feeds, the Animal eats, the FoodDistributor checks the FoodMagazine's stocks (and hands food to the Feeder).

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, I think we're getting too involved in the details of this particular example. :)  The general question is why you might want to use a visitor pattern instead of virtual methods in a base class.

Comment: @Jeremy I just wanted to stress the single responsibility principle. :-)

Comment: Use virtual methods and get rid of these ugly if/else ladders.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who pitched in. I agree that GiveFood should really be a virtual method on Mammal. But I was oversimplifying things a bit - I'm actually a bit restricted in what I can do with the animal and base Mammal class. Jeremy's solution with dynamics should solve the problem though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't usually like using `dynamic`, but this is one of the cases where I think it's appropriate:

```
public void Feed(Mammal mammal) {
  Anotherclass.GiveFood((dynamic)mammal);
}
```

That will resolve the correct overload at runtime, without knowing the type in advance.

Strictly speaking, this probably isn't going to be the fastest method, but as you point out, the alternatives can be a real pain to maintain, and/or hard to read.  In this case, dynamic dispatch is elegant and will automatically incorporate any overloads you add in the future.

As Chris Sinclair points out, you could also add a catchall method to detect any invalid calls and provide a friendlier exception than the runtime error you'd receive if no matching `GiveFood()` overload could be found:

```
public static class AnotherClass
{
  public static void GiveFood(Cat cat) {}
  public static void GiveFood(Dog dog) {}

  public static void GiveFood(Mammal mammal)
  {
    throw new AnimalNotRecognizedException("I don't know how to feed a " + mammal.GetType().Name + ".");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, won't this also throw run-time exceptions if one day `Rat` is added/passed in but no corresponding method was created at compile-time for the feeder? (of course, if/elseif/elseif/else might have the same problem, but at least the catch-all `else` case might be better handled with a nice exception. Of course, that's what unit tests could be used for as well so the missing method/exception never gets passed initial development) EDIT: Maybe a catchall `GiveFood(Mammal)` can be added to catch those?

Comment: Well, yes, it will throw if the application isn't set up to handle all valid cases properly, but if that's the case then it seems pretty likely you're going to run into problems somewhere along the line regardless.  I can see your point about throwing a friendlier exception, but the problem will still have to be corrected one way or another.  Maybe it's just me, but the elegance and maintainability of this approach outweighs the drawbacks.

Comment: And yes, adding a catchall method to throw a friendlier exception sounds like a good compromise to me.

Comment: Never occured to me to use dynamics. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's the animal's responsibility to process food, not the feeder. Otherwise you'll run into the problem you now have:

```
public void Feed(Mammal mammal) {
    if (mammal is Duck) 
    {
        ((Duck)mammal).PryOpenBeak();
        ((Duck)mammal).InsertFeedingTube();
        ((Duck)mammal).PourDownFood();
    }
}
```

And so on, although ducks aren't mammals.

Anyway, your `Mammal`  class should have an abstract method `Feed(Food food)`, and the animal itself will have to figure out how to process the food. This way when later adding a new mammal, you won't have to update the feeder with the feeding logic for this new mammal.

@Chris's comment: then the animal could implement the proper `IFoodXEater` interface that contains a `Feed(IFoodX)` method, and then the feeder can look that up, although then you're back at square one:

```
if (mammal is IFishEater)
{
    ((IFishEater)mammal).Feed(new Fish());
}
```

Comment: Well, to be fair, it might be the feeder's responsibility to figure out the right _kind_ of food to give the mammal. (but that also might be abstracted rather than if/elseif/elseif)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair then it becomes a whole different ball park, see edit.

Comment: @CodeCaster For sure, but then doing it with `IEatFoodX` is the same problem with a different name. Now the feeder is going to have something like `if (mammal is IEatFoodX) elseif (mammal is IEatFoodY)` and so on.

Comment: Notice that your edit has put the OP back in the same situation he is specifically trying to avoid.

Comment: Really, we're kind of _assuming_ what Zissou is doing. This may not be the case, it may be far more complicated, or simpler, or who knows. Zissou will have to abstract/polymorphise the concept however is appropriate. Perhaps there's a lookup table generated somewhere for the feeder to access. Perhaps for the sake of programmatic simplicity, the animal just has a method `GetFoodType()` and to hell with making sure it corresponds to the _real_ world by re-implementing reality.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Without knowing more about the problem, it's hard to say for sure. But the visitor pattern is often an effective technique for achieving double dispatch with compile time safety. Jeremy Todd's answer sidesteps all of that by using dynamic. And it's entirely possible a single virtual method on Mammal would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'd like to have the animals implement their own feeding method, but I'm a bit limited in what I can do with them. I was oversimplifying things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the effort of creating a type map, you can fake double dispatch like so:

[EDIT] This new, improved version handles subclasses better. If you have a class derived from another mammal class (such as `Pug` derived from `Dog` in the example below) then you don't need to explicitly add a feeder for class `Pug`  - it will automatically call the feeder for its base class, `Dog`.

But you can have a specific feeder for a derived class if you want, as demonstrated by the `Manx` class below.

Using `dynamic` is much much easier though! I just wanted to show how it could look if you weren't using `dynamic`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Mammal {}

    public class Cat: Mammal {}
    public class Pig: Mammal {}
    public class Dog: Mammal {}

    public class Pug:  Dog {}
    public class Manx: Cat {}

    public static class Feeder
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<Mammal>> map = createMap();

        static Dictionary<Type, Action<Mammal>> createMap()
        {
            return new Dictionary<Type, Action<Mammal>>
            {
                {typeof(Cat),  mammal => GiveFood((Cat)  mammal)},
                {typeof(Dog),  mammal => GiveFood((Dog)  mammal)},
                {typeof(Manx), mammal => GiveFood((Manx) mammal)}
            };
        }

        public static void GiveFood(Mammal mammal)
        {
            for (
                var currentType = mammal.GetType(); 
                typeof(Mammal).IsAssignableFrom(currentType);
                currentType = currentType.BaseType)
            {
                if (map.ContainsKey(currentType))
                {
                    map[currentType](mammal);
                    return;
                }
            }

            DefaultGiveFood(mammal);
        }

        public static void DefaultGiveFood(Mammal mammal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Feeding an unknown mammal.");
        }

        public static void GiveFood(Cat cat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Feeding the cat.");
        }

        public static void GiveFood(Manx cat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Feeding the Manx cat.");
        }

        public static void GiveFood(Dog dog)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Feeding the dog.");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        void test()
        {
            feed(new Cat());
            feed(new Manx());
            feed(new Dog());
            feed(new Pug());
            feed(new Pig());
            feed(new Mammal());
        }

        void feed(Mammal mammal)
        {
            Feeder.GiveFood(mammal);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This will work fine so long as Zissou is using `sealed` or rather avoiding much inheritance. If a `GermanShepard : Dog` all breeds/subclasses would have to be registered even if compatible. I only bring it up because Zissou's question/sample essentially handled inheritance/assignability by using the `is` operator.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I have tried to address that problem; it seems to work ok!

Comment: Wow, +1 for the `for` loop crawling up the inheritance tree. I'll have to remember that one. (EDIT: Damn, I already +1'd this question earlier)

Answer (score 2):

My Recommendation:

**Step 1**: Create an interface IMammal

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public interface IMammal
{
    void Feed();
}
```

**Step 2**: (Optional) Implement a Base class BaseMammal

```
public class BaseMammal : IMammal
{
    public void Feed()
    {
        Trace.Write("basic mammal feeding");
        //a basic implementation of feeding, common to all or most mammals
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: Implement your inherited classes

```
public class Cat : BaseMammal
{
    public void Feed()
    {
        Trace.Write("cat feeding");
        BePicky();//some custom cat like functionality
        base.Feed(); //and afterwards its still just a mammal after all
    }
}

public class Gruffalo : BaseMammal
{
    public void Feed()
    {
        Trace.Write("Gruffalo feeding");
        WeirdWayOfEating();//the base implementation is not appropriate
    }
}
```

**Step 4**: Use! (random example included)

```
List<IMammal> pets = new List<IMammal>()
    {
        new Cat(catValues),
        new Gruffalo(gruffaloValues)
    };

foreach(var pet in pets)
{
    pet.Feed();
}
```

Each animal will be fed by their own implementation. Lo and behold - your complex code is now simple. I would also recommend that you read "Head First Design Patterns", which explains this and many other concepts. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124

Comment: You're right, this is the better way of doing it, but I'm a bit limited in what I can do with the various animal and Mammal classes. As I said, I was simplifying the problem  a bit (maybe a bit too much).

Comment: time to take it to the more detailed version then? The basic architectural structure you posted will make it very difficult to adapt to changes, so in this case I feel "don't start from here" is a pretty legit response. However, if you are confined by existing code you are not allowed to change, then can you post something a little more concrete?

The question is - why are you limited? If the original code is not changable (3rd party) then you may be able to apply some form of adapter or similar. More info please :)

Answer (score 1):

If more than one animal shares the feeding behavior, I'll suggest to use the strategy pattern to encapsulate the feeding behavior in an interface and concrete implement each behavior for each group of animals

you will be using composition instead of inheritance

check the head first design patterns for this one I think it will be a good implementation in your case